# SSH from Linux to Windows Server 2019 using key-pair

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, ssh, automation, terraform

I’m trying to SSH to a Windows Server 2019 EC2 instance from a Linux machine. I’m trying to use key-pair authentication to access the server but it still asks for the admin password when using the private key. Im trying to figure this out manually before using Terraform to automate the process so that I can use one line SSH commands using the key and not have to use a password. Anyone know why it still asks for the password?

In my terraform setup I have a ssh connection with the following configuration:

```
connection {
type = "ssh"
host = aws_instance.file.public_ip
user = "administrator"
private_key = file(**)
script_path = "/Windows/Temp/terraform_%RAND%.bat"
password = var.windows_password
agent = false
timeout = 10m
}
```

My user data script has enabled OpenSSH on start up:

```
Add-WindowsCapabilty -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~0.0.1.0
Add-WindowsCapabilty -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~0.0.1.0
Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType 'Automatic'
Start-Service sshd
```

When I SSH into the ec2 instance using the private key file it still asks for the administrator password. I'm using the following command to SSH into the ec2:

```
ssh -i privateKeyFile administrator@ip_address
```

Comment: Did you install the Windows OpenSSH server on Windows first? What did you configure for Windows SSH user authentication? Edit your question with details.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post. Hopefully makes more sense now!

Comment: Did you setup SSH user authentication? Your goal is to use an SSH keypair to authenticate. Did you setup the public key on the SSH server? If you do not configure the server, how would it know the private key that you are using is a valid credential?

Comment: This is the part I'm struggling with. I'm using terraform to spin up the windows ec2. I need to be able to SSH from my linux machine (that is running terraform) to the windows machine using key-pair (or another passwordless method). I tried storing the key on the windows machine but I'm clearly doing something wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have a catch 22. You need to configure access in order to access. SSH on Windows is not native. The native method is to configure and use WinRM. Google search. There are many articles.